# Failure for tinytex in RStudio to produce a pdf file

Tags: r, latex

I am a beginner in Programming. I tried using tinytex to compile hadley wickham's Advanced R in `RStudio`. After hours of setting and package/font installing, another problem emerged:

I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log **_main.log**

> ! LaTeX Error: Environment sidebar
> undefined.

I have no idea what is going on. Thank you for everyone who helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. The solution is this:

> Problem was due to some changes in Markdown. See answer in https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/230

Solution is to update rmarkdown with the current github version:

update with:

```
remotes::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')
```

to revert your rmarkdown back to RStudio’s CRAN version, just uninstall rmarkdown, then reinstall it:

```
remove.packages(‘rmarkdown’)
install.packages(‘rmarkdown’)
```

You can also remove the remote installs of the two custom repos:

```
remove.packages(‘emo’)
remove.packages(‘sloop’)
```

The other packages I had to install due to compiling the book, are:

> devtools, bookdown, zeallot, lobstr, RSQLite, zeallot, dbplyr, bench, tidyr, ggbeeswarm

Answer (score -1):

It would seem you might be trying to build a website that duplicates the website built with bookdown.  There is no reason to do anthing like this.  The book is complete and freely available.

Just visit the following website to view the entire, Advanced R, by Hadley, book.

https://adv-r.hadley.nz/